# firmware registration failed

Tags: firmware

I got an error while booting Ubuntu 16.0.4 so, please 
give me solution on below problem.

```
dmi : firmware registration failed.
/dev/sda : clean,207462/249408 files, 1324583/9779712 blocks
```

Comment: any one has solution

Comment: What happens next? Does it prevent you from logging in?

Comment: I got also same error, and it just fails to boot and went complete black screen